# How to retrieve the value of a colum in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a table with the following colums:

> ```
> FileID | username | filename
> ```

I am using a gridview which has two colums:

> FileName | Download

In the download column i am having a button called Download which will be used to download files. Now i want to retrieve the fileID or Filename when i click Download button.

I tried this line to get the fileid but it was giving an error:

```
int FileID = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Value;
```

Error:
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Here's my aspx page code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="filelist" 
    Width="404px" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand" Height="131px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="fileid" HeaderText="fileid" InsertVisible="False" 
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="fileid" Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="userid" HeaderText="userid" SortExpression="userid" 
            Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="filename" HeaderText="FileName" 
            SortExpression="filename" />
        <asp:ButtonField HeaderText="Download" Text="Download" CommandName="download"/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="filelist" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [FileDetails] WHERE ([userid] = @userid)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="userid" SessionField="userid" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would access the value in a column inside a datagrid

```
GridView1.Rows[rowId].Cells[columnId].Value
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use your first `BoundField` to get the `fileid`:

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Control)sender).NamingContainer;
int FileID = int.Parse(row.Cells[0].Text);
```

**Edit**: When you're handling the GridView's `RowCommand` event, the above code does not work since the `sender` is the GridView instead of the Button. Then you'll find your Button in the [`GridViewCommandEventArgs.CommandSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewcommandeventargs.commandsource.aspx):

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
int FileID = int.Parse(row.Cells[0].Text);
```

Comment: 1st Line gives the following Exception:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow'.